# Rails nested attributes: doesn't update selected field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and I have a nested attributes in archive form that does display in a select field multiple harddisks:

```
<%= form_with(model: archive, local: true, url: archive_path(@archive), method: :put) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :shelfmark %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :shelfmark %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label "Harddisk" %><br />
      <%= form.select :harddisk_id, Harddisk.order(bezeichnung: :asc).collect {|a| [ a.label, a.id ] } %> 
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In archives_controller:

```
  def archive_params
    params.require(:archive)
      .permit(:shelfmark, :harddisk_id, harddisk_attributes: [:id, :label])
  end
```

When I select a harddisk for example with id: 2 it doesn't update the harddisk_id attribute on archive table. It still remains with harddisk_id: 1 (instead of 2).

The rails server log:

```
   Started PATCH "/archives/5" for ::1 at 2018-02-09 13:52:10 +0100
Processing by ArchivesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aas9eTl1Vb0JP+KHncyBKts7s1ZJD4l0jRz9wiNi3aiwwDYwkJbt9FXAy6T23sNYONJB1npoprvFtULReEKWIQ==", 
              "archive"=>{"shelfmark"=>"bar", "harddisk_attributes"=>

{"id"=>"1"}, "harddisk_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Update Archive", "id"=>"2"}
      Archive Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `archive`.* FROM `archive` WHERE `archive`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Harddisk Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `harddisks`.* FROM `harddisks` WHERE `harddisks`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Now it tries to update the harddisk_id record but throws an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Harddisk with ID=1 for
>   Archive with ID=2):

Comment: it most likely means that `archive.harddisk` is `nil` (no value)

Comment: You said that `harddisk_id` is an Archive attribute, and not Harddisk attribute? Then you should not use `harddisk_fields.select :harddisk_id`. But you can use `harddisk_fields.select :id` instead or use `form.select :harddisk_id`

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario when I use harddisk_fields.select :id instead then the select fields are shown but the harddisk_id entry in Archive table is not updated instead a new harddisk entry is created on Harddisk table. I can't understand this strange behaviour.

Comment: After a lot of trying, I could make a babystep progress and I updated the post to the current state of issue.

Comment: Do you really intend to have Harddisk's `:capacity` attribute be updateable inside the Archive form? Because if you updated this, all other Archive associated to that particular Harddisk that you just updated will also be affected, because they are all pointing to just one record in the database. However, if you wish to be able to modify harddisk capacity, so that even if two archive records are associated to say Harddisk_1, then you can still have different values for capacity instead of being a shared value. If this is what you want, you'd need another join table named HarddiskArchive

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong: dont use `harddisk_fields.select :id` but use `form.select :harddisk_id`. The former will try to update the `id` of the harddisk record, but you do not want this as you'd want instead to update the `harddisk_id` of the archive record.

Comment: yes, you were right, now it tries to update the harddisk_id property but throws an error see my updated post.

Comment: regarding your earlier comment to harddisk capacity: I don't need the field and removed it from the archive form. Do I understand it correctly that I don't need a form_for then? Is my updated form in the post correct?

Comment: Yes you do not need the `form.fields_for` (not the `form_for`) if you are just going to update the `archive.harddisk_id`, and that you are not updating any of the harddisk attributes (i.e. capacity).

Comment: If you remove all of the `form.fields_for :harddisk do ... end` and just replace it with `form.text_field :harddisk_id`, the error you just mentioned should go away.

Comment: wohoo! Thank you very much! Can you provide this as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: good to hear it worked. Alright, I'm gonna write this down now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just meant to update:

```
archive.harddisk_id
```

and not update any of the associated harddisk's attributes:

```
archive.attribute.capacity
archive.attribute.created_at
archive.attribute.updated_at
```

Then, you do not need `nested_attributes` for this. So:

### Solution

Replace all of

`form.fields_for :harddisk do ... end`

...with...

`form.select :harddisk_id`

Also, you can now safely remove any trace of nested_attributes as you do not need them anymore:

- remove `harddisk_attributes` from your controller method `archive_params`
- remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :harddisk` on your `Archive` model.